# Converter coluna de dataframe pandas com array em string (Python)

Tags: python, array, lista, pandas, dataframe

Tenho um data frame pandas em Python, em que uma das colunas está trazendo os valores em um array(lista). Gostaria de remover os colchetes ([]), para converter em string. Já tentei com strip, regex e nada.

Está assim:

[image: Está assim]

Gostaria que ficasse assim:

[image: Gostaria que ficasse assim:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o applymap do pandas junto com isinstance:

```
df.applymap(lambda x: x if not isinstance(x, list) else " ".join(x))
```

O data frame recebe o valor de x sem modificações caso o mesmo não seja uma lista, caso seja uma lista faz uma concatenação dos elementos. Funciona para lista vazia.

Answer (score 0):

Uma forma que funcionou corretamente e fica muito rápido foi:

```
df['liststring'] = df['lists'].apply(lambda x: x[1:-1])
```

A nova coluna `liststring` recebe a *string* da lista existente em `df['lists']`.